# How to fix this nav bar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The problem is that when I narrow the screen, the bar breaks into two rows.
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOq4V.png)

So my question is how can I collapse them instead of breaking the row?

Update:
This is an example I tried:
https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

The problem appears if I make the font size and nav header a bit larger:

```
.navbar-brand, .navbar-nav li a {
  line-height: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  padding-top: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: The examples you link to collapse correctly. Have you tried their HTML?

Comment: It's best to include code in a post so we know what you're dealing with.

Comment: Please include the code relevant to your problem in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Should be fine in a full width container. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RVVLLe

In a normal use case you wouldn't have it in a column like in the bootstrap docs.

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-9 pull-md-3 bd-content">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
      <!-- Navbar content -->
    </nav>
</div>
```

If you did you would need to change the break point to collapse the content when it breaks.

Comment: I just figured that the problem is that I made the font size and nav bar larger than they're in the example. The question is updated with the css code I have. Do you have any idea?